# I cannot make a copy constructor for a bidirectional map

Tags: c++, c++11

I am in my first year of c++ at university and in some days i have exam.
I work hard for this exam not only to succeed but to succeed with the best mark.
In this code that I post I have to make a bidirectional map which i was able to do and some other functions for it.
The problem comes when i try to make a copy constructor for this bidirectional map.
I know it is a  little shameful to come to you guys with this minor problem but I last give a try.
If someone of you has patience to help me i will be very happy to succeed with high mark at my c++ exam.
So here is the header where i create a bidirectional map.This contains 2 maps: one stores the key and the value and other stores the value like key and the first key like the value. The problem comes when i have to do a copy constructor and I not have the optimal knowledge to do this.

```
#ifndef BIMAP_H_INCLUDED
#define BIMAP_H_INCLUDED

#include<map>
#include <utility>

template <class T>

class BidirectionalMap
{
public:
    BidirectionalMap(){};
    BidirectionalMap(typename std::multimap<T,T>::iterator beg, typename std::multimap<T,T>::iterator end)
    {
          m1.insert(beg,end
    }
    void insert(T a, T b)
    {
        m1.insert(std::pair<T,T> (a,b));
        m2.insert(std::pair<T,T> (b,a));
    }
    BidirectionalMap& operator =(const BidirectionalMap &c)
    {
        m1=c.m1;
        m2=c.m2;
        return *this;
    }
    const T& at(const T &a) const
    {
        if(m2.find(a)!=m2.end()) return m2.at(a);
        else return m1.at(a);
    }
    int count(const T &a) const
    {
        if(m2.find(a)!=m2.end()) return m2.count(a);
        else if(m1.find(a)!=m1.end()) return m1.count(a);
            else return 0;
    }
    void erase(const T &a)
    {
        if(m1.find(a)!=m1.end())
        {
            T b=m1[a];
            m1.erase(a);
            m2.erase(b);
        }
        else
        {
            T b=m2[a];
            m2.erase(a);
            m1.erase(b);
        }
    }
    int size() const
    {
        return m1.size();
    }
    typename std::map<T,T>::const_iterator begin() const
    {
        return m1.begin();
    }
    typename std::map<T,T>::const_iterator end() const
    {
        return m1.end();
    }

private:
    std::map<T,T> m1;
    std::map<T,T> m2;
};

#endif // BIMAP_H_INCLUDED
```

And here is the main() where i use that bidirectional map.Do not focus on 2,3,4 but only on 5 because just there I have no idea.

```
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include "bimap.h"

struct LengthSum
{
  int length;

  LengthSum():length(0) {}

  void operator()(const std::pair<std::string, std::string>& p)
  {
    length += p.first.length();
    length += p.second.length();
  }
};

const int max = 1000;

int main()
{
  int yourMark = 1;
  // 2-es
  BidirectionalMap<int> fun;
  for( int i = 1; i <= max; ++i )
    fun.insert( i, i + max );

  BidirectionalMap<std::string> tel;
  tel.insert( "Aniko", "+36(70)555-8124" );
  tel.insert( "Botond", "+36(30)555-4321" );

  const BidirectionalMap<std::string> ctel = tel;

  if ( fun.at( 1 ) == (1 + max) &&
       ctel.at( "+36(30)555-4321" ) == "Botond" )
  {
    yourMark = ctel.count( "Aniko" ) +
               fun.count( max * 2 ) +
           ctel.count( "Unknown" );
  }

  // 3-as
  tel.erase( "+36(70)555-8124" );
  if ( 0 == tel.count( "Aniko" ) &&
       max == fun.size() )
  {
    yourMark = ctel.size() + tel.size();
  }
  // 4-es
  const int l = std::for_each( ctel.begin(), ctel.end(), LengthSum() ).length;
  yourMark = l/10;

  // 5-os
  std::map<double, double> md;
  md[1.12] = 8.8;
  md[5.4] = 7.5;

  std::multimap<int, int> mmi;
  mmi.insert( std::make_pair( 1, 2 ) );
  mmi.insert( std::make_pair( 3, 6 ) );
  mmi.insert( std::make_pair( 5, 8 ) );
  //Here is the problem because i don`t know to do this :
  const BidirectionalMap<int> b( mmi.begin(), mmi.end() );//??
  const BidirectionalMap<double> bd( md.begin(), md.end() );//??
  if ( b.at(8) == 5 )
  {
    yourMark = b.size() +
               bd.size() +
           b.count( 9 );
  }
  std::cout << "Your mark is " << yourMark;
  std::endl( std::cout );
}
```

For the 2,3,4 marks i succeeded but when it comes for the best mark(5 in my country) i crashed.
So if you have the time and patience PLEASE help me :(

Comment: Your title is quite poor. Please update your post with a more appropriate title that describes the issue you are having.

Comment: And what is the actual problem?

Comment: Please narrow down the code to the parts that give you the problem. Preferably you should create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problems you're having. Also, if you have crashes, use a debugger to find exactly where it crashes, and point it out for us. If you have build errors then edit your question to include the complete error log.

Comment: I made some changes to my post...It is ok now guys?

Comment: Your question should focus on the Problem you have and not the backstory why you need it for good grades and such. That being said: I'd look for a better Title, Define your problem well (what do you want to achieve, what does not work *exactly*), and try to avoid generalities (`here to i do my stuff`, `here comes the problem`, `i don't know how to do this`,...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are trying to copy a multimap into a map. Multimaps can have multiple items with the same index stored, while a map has only one item per index.

So, you may have to iterate over the incoming range and insert the map element wise into your maps. What you do if you have multiple indices stored in the multimap you have to decide for yourself.

Edit:
To be compatible with both map and multimap you can always make the iterator a template argument:

```
template<typename TIter>
BidirectionalMap(TIter beg, TIter end) {
    for(TIter it = beg; it != end; ++it) {
        // insert elements
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand what you said but believe me that I don`t know how to wise insert the multimap content to my bimap. If you can give me an example?

Comment: Yes I could. But it would be better if you look at some documentation and try for yourself. For example, This reference for [multimap::begin()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/begin/) shows a nice example on how to iterate over a multimap. From there, you can easily `insert` (hint) it into your map. And, in the end you learned a bit about C++ and reading documentation :)

Comment: When it comes to this i get an error that `BidirectionalMap(typename std::multimap<T>::iterator beg, typename std::multimap<T>::iterator end)` has not 4 template arguments. why this shoud be when in my copy constructor i should have only 2 : `const BidirectionalMap<int> b( mmi.begin(), mmi.end() )` ?

Comment: I added my answer with an example for a templated constructor. But this goes far from your original answer. Maybe it would be a good time to show your progress and new errors in your question.

Comment: Omg!! Thanck you so much!! I made it!!! Thanck you again!! I edit my post to see how i made it and please give your opinion :)

Comment: @lero congratulations :). Just as information: If you manage to solve the problem and want to share it at StackOverflow, the best practice is to create an answer for your own question and show what you did there. So, people who visit the question will see the answer and how it was solved while still seeing what the problem was. Also, others can add opinions to your solution and maybe give hints what they could improve. And don't forget to accept your answer, so the question does not show up as unsolved.

Comment: I`ve did what you said. Thank`s a lot again!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this with help from @MatthiasB

```
     BidirectionalMap(Titer beg, Titer end)
        {
           for(Titer it = beg; it != end; ++it)
           {
               m1.insert(*it);
               m2.insert(std::pair<T,T> (it->second,it->first));
           }
```